# Creating nested dropdown in dash

Tags: python, plotly-dash, dashboard

I want to create the nested dropdown in `dash`.
There should be only one dropdown placeholder and when we hover on any option that option shows its sub-dropdown and whatever option we choose it turns black rest is grey.

I tried looking in `dash` documentation, but didn't find anything useful.

Comment: It is better to post here the code you already wrote.